# After upgrading from Win 10 Home to Win 10 Pro, I still can not see "Local Users and Groups"

Tags: windows, authentication, active-directory, windows-10, mmc

I need to manage Hyper-V administrator group to create Emulator. So, I need to access local users and group option in control panel.
I've tried to add snapin in mmc.exe it does not allow me to add.
it shows

---

### Local Users and Groups

### This snapin may not be used with this edition of Windows 10. To manage user accounts for this computer, use the User Accounts tool in the Control Panel.

### OK

This is one of reasons I've upgraded to window 10 pro. what would be best way to resolve this,..?

Answer (score 0):

Try Control Panel -> Administrator Tools -> Local Users and Groups -> Users instead.